# Random reboots or freezes with ubuntu 22.04 and Ryzen/Amd

Tags: kernel, amd-ryzen

I have a Ryzen 1700X machine with Radeon RX570 and I get random reboots or freezes.

I think it has to do with:

```
et 04 14:07:00 tsayao-dell kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
set 04 14:07:00 tsayao-dell kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 7: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000000108
set 04 14:07:00 tsayao-dell kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 1ffffb446ef10 MISC d012000201000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 500b000000000 
set 04 14:07:00 tsayao-dell kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:800f11 TIME 1693847212 SOCKET 0 APIC 7 microcode 8001129
```

I did try:

- acpi=noapic
- clearcpuid=514 rcu_nocbs=0-15 pci=noaer idle=nowait

Did not work.

Also tried using AMD Radeon proprietary drivers.

Also have this warnings:

```
[    0.300380] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.302075] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP8.VGA], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)
[    0.302084] fbcon: Taking over console
[    0.302094] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
[    0.302099] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Scope (0x0010)
[    0.302102] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP8.HDAU], AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/dswload2-162)
[    0.302108] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
```

Happened on the original 22.04 kernel, but now I'm using 6.2.0 (problem still happens).

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Random reboots or freezes tend to by memory issues.  I'd start with a memtest. You can forget the boot messages. Those are not for us to fix.

Comment: You can see the system logs leading up to the last crash with: `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. Read `man journalctl`. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`.

Comment: I've tried to remove on memory card and test, then another and test. Reboot still happens with both (isolated). No probably not a memory card issue.